# 2D elastic collision using Matlab

Tags: matlab, collision-detection

I recently started using Matlab and am modeling hard spheres in 2D.
I have n particles, their positions are given by two arrays x(n,1) and y(n,1).
The simulation has N time steps.

I set up a distance matrixt:

```
Distance: x(1)-x(1), x(2)-x(1), x(3)-x(1), 
          x(2)-x(1), x(2)-x(2), x(3)-x(2), 
          x(3)-x(1), x(3)-x(2), x(3)-x(3),
```

The diagonal is zero.
I tried to use a for loop in combination with a for command to see if a collision has taken place, by comparing particle distances to 2*radius. If they do collide I want to find the collision angle to create a new reference frame and treat the collision as a 1D collision in that frame.

```
for i=1:number_particles
  for j=(i+1):number_particles

    if distance_2D(i,j) < 2*radius             %Collision with other particle

    dy = position_y(i)-position_y(j);
    dx = position_x(i)-position_x(j);

    P(i,j) = atan2(dy,dx);      

    end
 end
end
```

However, I am not sure if atan2 is the correct command to use to extract the angle that I am looking for. Also it seems like there should be a much neater way of setting the solution up in Matlab.

Should I be using atan(y/x) or atan2d(y,x). And then from there?

Comment: atan2 is $2\pi$ periodic whereas atan is $pi$ periodic, so you probably do want atan2. Is the distance_2D(i,j) function just elements of that matrix you have above, or did you define the function elsewhere? You know you need to do something like $\sqrt{(y_i-y_j)^2+(x_i-x_j)^2}$ right?

Comment: @Kai Sikorski The distance_2D is defined elsewhere, as this: %% ---- Calculate distances between two particles distance_2D = sqrt(distance_x.^2+distance_y.^2); I will go ahead and use atan2 and see if I can get any further with this.